# JPAのQueryでcount(*)に失敗する

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

SpringJPAの、org.springframework.data.domain.Pageをリクエストする際、下記のようなエラーが発生します。

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

モデルは多対多で、モデルのマッピングは正常に行えており、
下記メソッドをコメントアウトすることでエラーは解消します。
発行メソッドは下記です。

```
@Query("select e from Entity e "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH e.relation c "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.categoryFilter f "
        + "where e.deleteTs is null "
        + "and f.uid in (?1)")
Page<Entity> findByFilters(List<String> filters, Pageable pageable);
```

また、これの戻り値をListにすると、エラーは発生しなくなるため、
PageクラスのtotalElementsを取得することができないというエラーなのはわかっています。
似たようなクエリを流しても、エラーにはなりませんでした。

バグでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query(value = "select e from Entity e "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH e.relation c "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.categoryFilter f "
        + "where e.deleteTs is null "
        + "and f.uid in (?1)",
       countQuery = "select e from Entity e ...")
```

left join fetchしてるのにcountQueryが未指定なのが原因だと思います。